# Relocating the DocumentRoot using .htaccess files

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to get all http requests to go to a different local directory than where DocumentRoot points to:

The web server config:

```
<VirtualHost 1.2.3.4:80>
DocumentRoot /local/home/me/example.com
ServerName   example.com
```

However, the entire (PHP) code for this site is not at DocumentRoot but rather in a subdir:

```
/local/home/me/example.com/code/
```

Currently, to access the site, I have to use URLs that include the `/code/` subdir. I like to get rid of that so that `http://example.com/` accesses `/local/home/me/example.com/code/`

I understand that the right way is to make DocumentRoot point to the subdir. My web hoster won't let me change this setting, though (in fact, that's how I had it before, when I hosted this site on my private web server where I could set the DocumentRoot just like that).

I now hope I can accomplish this with rewrites in .htaccess file(s). I just don't understand how.

My questions, in particular:

- What are the rewrite rules for this?
- Can I make a single .htaccess file for all paths, or do I have to have one per subdir (e.g. there are subdirs inside `/code/` - do they each need an individual .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1):

You can use this code in your `/local/home/me/example.com/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!code/).*)$ code/$1 [L,NC]
```

`(?!code/)` is negative lookahead that will check if request already doesn't start with `/code/` and will add this if condition is true.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation of what the rule actually does. Sadly, though, it leads to an internal error 500. I guess that's because the subdir has its own rewrite rules which conflict somehow. I'll keep fiddling. This answer may still help others, I hope.

Comment: `/code/.htaccess` shouldn't matter. For 500 error always look into your Apache error.log and see what the actual error is.